# Convert HTML string

Tags: iphone, html

This could be the simple one question but I am not able to get the exact data from the below string.
Following Data I want to extract but I am unable to do this.
1. Description
2. When Text
3. Where Text
4. Click here link

How do I convert this in objective C.

```
<p>
    <a href="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~a/uD33rOAaHkAZywKvO6ntrkv_ETU/0/da">
        <img src="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~a/uD33rOAaHkAZywKvO6ntrkv_ETU/0/di" border="0" ismap="true"></img>
    </a>
<br/>
    <a href="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~a/uD33rOAaHkAZywKvO6ntrkv_ETU/1/da">
        <img src="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~a/uD33rOAaHkAZywKvO6ntrkv_ETU/1/di" border="0" ismap="true"></img>
    </a>
</p>


<p>
    <a href="http://mumbai.burrp.com/events/little-theatre-ncpa_semshook_nariman-point_mumbai/19313517316">
        <img src="/images/evt/c/6/photo_little-theatre-ncpa_nariman-point_mumbai@c6s6kwyg_2wat_1_300.jpg"/>
    </a>
</p>                


<p>
    Tenzin is a Tibetan born and raised in India. Yearning to explore his true homeland, he impulsively hops on his motorcycle and embarks on a personal quest: to find his identity and discover the indescribable beauty and wonders of his magnificent homeland. But Tibet is a nation under siege from a repressive regime. While Tenzin encounters friendship, camaraderie and even love along the way, he cannot escape the horrors of a political world he wants no part of. Looking only for the way to peace, both within himself and for the land he loves, Tenzin must find the courage to pursue the truth, even if it means facing terrible dangers to find his Semshook.
<strong>Language</strong>: Hindi, English, Tibetan Film with English subtitles
<strong>Directed by</strong>: Siddharth Anand Kumar
<strong>Cast</strong>: Tenzin Younden, Tenzin Choedon and Tensin Woebhum
</p>

<p>
    <strong>When:</strong> Friday Feb, 24
</p>    

<p>
    <strong>Where:</strong> Little Theatre (NCPA), Nariman Poin
</p>

<p>
    <a href="http://mumbai.burrp.com/events/index.html">More events</a> in Mumbai
</p>

<p>
    <a href="http://mumbai.burrp.com/events/date/this-weekend">Click Here</a> to view more events happening <strong>this weekend</strong> in Mumbai
</p>
```

I have used this code but this gives me plain text, I want link related to that text means like text and link combination.

```
NSScanner *theScanner;
    NSString *text = nil;
    theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];

    while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL] ; 

        [theScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text] ;

        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text] withString:@""];
    }
    //
    html = [html stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSLog(@"html======================>%@",html);
    return html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of XML Parsing and NSString methods.